# How to create Cloth Simulation for Deflating a net wrapped around balloon in Blender?

Tags: animation, physics, shape-keys, collision, timeline

I am trying to wrap a net (made out of torus shapes) around a balloon.
As the balloon deflate, I hope to make the net get flat and flat (on the ground.
I was exploring the inflate and deflate on Blender, but I have trouble figuring out how to add motions/other physics to the net.

Which feature can I use to make the net to collapse and get flat along with the deflated balloon?
Would I have to parent it and make it collide to a flat plane surface?

[image: picture plan]
Describing my plan: inflated (nice inflated circular shape with a net wrapped around) at frame 1 and deflated (winkly and flat rubber balloon) at frame 100.

Here are some of the tutorials I watched related to my interests, inflate and deflate, applying cloth and collision, possible shape keys. Many of the tutorials I watched the collision usually stay static. It hold its solid shape, doesn't deflate like the balloon.

[Blender - inflate or deflate any model](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R5aUkq8kVDg)

[How to create a soft body in blender 2.8](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IxcR_s3_VMs)

[Make anything inflated](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F9xzCOWBJLM&t=7s)

[image: balloon deflated around 100 frame but the net is solid]

[image: 9 torus joined - shape keys]

Comment: Maybe create a spherical cage that will have the cloth simulation, and give your net + balloon a Mesh Deform modifier with this cage as Target?

Comment: @moonboots Hello! When you say spherical cage, is it like put a new big sphere around the balloon and net? (Just like Quick Effects (Domain)

Comment: Yes that's it, it needs to be test though so that the torus don't intersect with the balloon

Comment: @moonboots Thank you! Do you suggest that I add any additional physics to the balloons or the net? 
I am waiting for Blender to process 'MeshDeform - Object: spherical cage' applied to both balloon and net (no physics applied to balloon and the net). My laptop is taking forever to process :( ...

I accidentally tried one with net (collision applied) and balloon (cloth), the spherical cage wrapped it around and looked shrunk (I could see the white net in some parts - wonder if this is a glitch)

Comment: Is the net supposed to stick to the balloon or is it another object (in real life) so when your balloon will deflate there will be some gap between the net and the balloon?

Comment: @moonboots Hello! It's supposed towrap it around the balloon, there should be a little gap that when the balloon deflates, the net would be on/around it. It is like slime in a net (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YZtaXbNorvU) I could not really find a good picture that visualizes the net around the balloon. Hope that makes sense